# Performance difference between native MySQL partitioning and backend based partitioning?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, scalability

Say I have two scenarios, with same amount of data, for example one table with 500  rows.
In first, I use one query to to query partitioned MySQL table, and let the rest of the logic to MySQL engine to get my result.

In the second case, I create 5 tables with max 100 rows.
I then programatically traverse those tables until the record is found, like this (pseudo-code):

```
fetchedData = query table1
if fetchedData == null 
  fetchedData = query table2
    if fetchedData == null
            ...
      fetchedData = query table5
```

The main drawback here I see is that I potentially query database 5 times instead of 1, depending in which table the record is stored. But since the queries are smaller and more targeted, they should give me faster response time. Or should I just leave it to MySQL partitioning? And let's discount the maintainability in second case.

Comment: As always with performance questions, **there is no correct answer**. This is highly variable based on your data, your hardware, and your load patterns. You need to create a benchmark of your own and test exhaustively on whatever hardware you have available. The closer to the production hardware the better. If it's actually the production hardware, fantastic.

Comment: That being said, you probably want to go with database built-ins before you go and hack together something of your own. You only do that when you have no other option.

Comment: @tadman - There _is_ a correct answer.  It does not vary with data/hardware/load.  _Neither_ partitioning is of _any_ benefit for the scenario given.

Comment: @RickJames Given the trivial amounts of data in the example, I'm not sure there'd be any point in partitioning, but if that was, say, 500B rows, the answer might be very counter-intuitive.

Comment: Even a few millions rows _could_ lead to `PARTITION` being useful.  But there are very few use cases where there is a performance benefit.  I would insist on more info on the queries before getting into details.  (I see no need to "close", given that 500 rows was specified.)

Answer (score 1):

Neither.

500 rows is trivial.  Even if MySQL could do things in parallel, it would not help any.

Use a suitable index -- Often that helps tremendously.

Your particular pseudo code is no better than what can be done with a MySQL query with a `LIMIT 1` on the end to stop the query before scanning everything.  So, again, I say "neither type of partitioning will help at all".